# to start timer in angular js when an input is given

Tags: javascript, angularjs, timer

when the user select an item from the select form input only, then timer should start. Don't know how to trigger it.

I am using the timer module from **http://siddii.github.io/angular-timer/**. I'm able to stop timer. How to start it again?

```
<\timer interval="1000"> 
    {{hours}} hours, 
    {{minutes}} minutes, 
    {{seconds}} seconds {{millis}} 
<\timer/>
```

Answer (score 0):

Reading the [documentation](https://github.com/siddii/angular-timer/blob/master/examples/angularjs-single-timer.html) may help.

So in your Controller:

```
angular.module('MyApp', ['timer'])
    .controller('MyAppController', ['$scope', function ($scope) {
        $scope.timerRunning = true;
        $scope.startTimer = function (){
            $scope.$broadcast('timer-start');
            $scope.timerRunning = true;
        };
        $scope.stopTimer = function (){
            $scope.$broadcast('timer-stop');
            $scope.timerRunning = false;
        };
        $scope.$on('timer-stopped', function (event, data){
            console.log('Timer Stopped - data = ', data);
        });
    }]);
```

Your view:

```
<select ng-options="thing in things" ng-change="startTimer()">
  {{thing}}
</select>    
<timer/>
```

Again, all this in in the docs.

Hope it helps.